# How do you parse a custom formatted date time string into a datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is for Microsoft SQL Server

I have an audit table with a timestamp represented as a string - timestamps are in multiple locale-specific representations (eg some are in mm/dd others are dd/mm)

I know some rows that I'm interested in have a timestamp string in the format of dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss

I want to write a query that will return rows where the timestamp string is NOT in that format so I imagine something like this (with an imaginary PARSEDATE function)

```
WHERE PARSEDATE(timestamp) IS NOT NULL
```

Everything I've read about T-SQL datetime functions seem to involve well defined format codes eg 112 but I don't see a generalized way of being able to provide a custom date time format string for parsing?

Comment: Do the formatting not in SQL but in your client code (C#, Java, Python)

Comment: I don't have control over the client code in this case, this is data that was uploaded from elsewhere

Comment: There is a function called ISDATE(). Just use WHERE ISDATE(TIMESTAMP) = 1. Just be careful. Just because it can be parsed into a date, doesn't mean it's the date you expect. You already know you have a variety of date formats.

Comment: That sounds really tricky. Unless your row specifies if the date format is dd/mm or mm/dd, you'll have no accurate way of knowing how to parse the date. Otherwise, you could use some of the pattern matching abilities of [LIKE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) and do something like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE timestamp NOT LIKE '__/__/__ __:__:__'`

Comment: @Mr Moose - I'm starting to agree with your suggestion - I think in the case of such a specific structure here, using a pattern match is probably the best way to go about it

Comment: @blue18hutthutt - I'm not sure how else you could accurately perform it if you aren't sure of the dateformat for data in a given row. Give it a try and see if it works for you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Set the format before running your query.

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```

In your query

```
WHERE ISDATE(timestamp) = 1
```

More information can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)

Comment: This is very useful, however it's not quite what I want because the different DATEFORMAT settings still allows for some 'fuzzy' matching ..I need more precise matching because this approach would allow for multiple representations of say dmy ..I'm looking for a very specific encoding. I think the other user's answer of a pattern match would be more appropriate here. But ISDATE is very useful!

Comment: I think the specifics are controlled by the language